# Having problems printing on Firefox when displaying large content inside "float: left/right" element inside "display: table" element

Tags: html, css, firefox, printing

This is the code that i'm trying...

```
<div style="display: table">
    <div style="display: table-cell">
        <div style="float: left">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,

             ...10,000 more lines
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When using Google chrome(any version), it runs okay.  This is how the printer looks like:

[image]

But when i try it on firefox(any version) printer version and it looks like this:

[image]

"float: left" is needed, and we can assume we need more that one column, the display in desktop and printer should be the same.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Not sure what is the need of `float:left` here?

Comment: It's a large project where they have their own grid system that utilizes float left.

Comment: I get the same thing. When testing with `<table>`, `<tr>`, and `<td>` it works correctly, so you could use those. This also makes me think that you could have found a bug... although I am absolutely not certain about that.

Comment: _“It's a large project where they have their own grid system that utilizes float left”_ - yeah ok, but _what for_ actually - in this particular instance? You do not even seem to have more than one single column here, so you should be able to at least overwrite float in your print stylesheet …?

Comment: @CBroe No matter how many columns we have the result is the same.

Comment: We are able to overwrite "float: left" and apply specific @print style but it doesn't fix the problem on all the pages.

Comment: Do you need this to print “as it looks on desktop”, i.e. multiple columns (where applicable), etc.? Otherwise, I’d just try to overwrite float and table stuff completely in the print stylesheet.

Comment: @CBroe i need to print all the columns as it looks on Desktop

Answer (score 0):

There are normal equivalent tags:

`<div style="display: table">` => `<table>`

`<div style="display: table-row">` => `<tr>`

`<div style="display: table-cell">` => `<td>`

Using `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` seems to solve the problem. Since they are supposed to do the exact same thing, but have been around a lot longer, they are a good alternative. From what I can read the `display` tables are not often used. See:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display

> Gross but sometimes useful.